# How to add Maven to the Path variable?

Tags: windows, maven, path

I have downloaded the [maven 3.5.0](http://apache.cs.utah.edu/maven/maven-3/3.8.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.zip) from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). I have set it in the path:

```
C:\apache-maven-3.5.0
```

Then i treid to add it to the path of `Windows 7` as below:

1. Right click on my computer
2. Properties
3. Advanced System Setting
4. Environment Variable
5. New user variable and added `Maven_Home` with value `C:\apache-maven-3.5.0`
6. Add it to path variable with: `%Maven_Home%\bin`
7. Open `cmd` and ask for `mvn -version` in **desktop**

*Result*:

**It does not recognize maven**

Comment: Can you `mvn` command in `C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin` ?

Comment: Yes, it works fine from its directory. so it workd.

Comment: Make sure you have `;%MAVEN_HOME%;` in your `%PATH%` system environment variable. The semicolon delimiters are important.

Comment: https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem get solved when i edit the `path` variable with `;%Maven_Home%\bin;` so i should add the `;` before and after it.

Comment: `;` separates several paths but if nothing is behind it the last could be omitted.

Answer (score 72):

***In windows:***

Download the latest version of Maven from the http://maven.apache.org/ and Navigate to Use --> Download --> Download the Binary zip archive.

**1)** After the download, unzip the folder and copy it to the folder. (Lets say i have copied to c:\program files\apache-maven-3.52.

**2)** **Setting the path of Maven in environment Variables:** 
Search the Environment Variable --> Edit the System Environment variables--> Navigate to Advanced tab --> Environment Variables

**i) MAVEN_HOME :** Click New --> Variable Name : MAVEN_HOME , Variable Value: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.2

**ii) M2_HOME :** Click New --> Variable Name : M2_HOME , Variable Value: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.2

**iii) Edit the 'Path'** Environment Variable --> %M2_HOME%\bin

**Testing whether Maven is installed:**
mvn -version

***References:-***
http://www.baeldung.com/install-maven-on-windows-linux-mac

**NOTE : In point iii don't forget to put semicolon(;) before and after.**

Comment: In Windows 10, this does not work at all. It still says "...not recognized as an internal or external command", even after restart. WITH or WITHOUT the ;'s at both ends.

Comment: I don't know which version of windows you were using  in 2020 however windows 10 seems to be working perfectly with these instructions.

Comment: Which place, user variables or system variables when you click new?

Comment: If you are struggling to get the iii) step working, in the system path, just add

C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.x.y\bin (Replacing x and y with your version number)

to your path variable instead of using the M2_HOME variable. 
This isn't ideal, as you will now have to change two variables if your path updates or changes, but it's a quick fix.

Comment: Restart your PC after adding the path, hope this helps!

Answer (score 16):

1. Open command console
2. copy this
      **set PATH="c:\program files\apache-maven-3.x.y\bin";%PATH%**
3. cahnge the path accordingly
4. click enter

it's all set and now check mvn -version

Comment: This only sets for that console alone. If you open another console or process, this won't reflect there. The other answer covers adding environmental variables and adding to PATH globally.

Comment: works, upvote this guy

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and fixed the issue by:

- Adding the M2_HOME to the USER VARIABLES
- Adding the MAVEN_HOME to the USER VARIABLES
- Adding the BIN folder to the PATH in the SYSTEM VARIABLES

(conform this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfCWg5ay5B0)

Then i could run `mvn -version` in a NEW command terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you download the **Binary zip file** from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi. Then it should work fine by adding it to the path variable as mentioned in other answers. I've accidentally downloaded the src.zip file and of course it didn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding

1. `MAVEN_HOME` variable (C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.2) and `M2_HOME` variable (C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin).
2. Add `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` to the path in system variables . 
   Then mvn -version in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally I would add this information that worked for me

After I opened the Environment Variables and followed these steps:

System variables > path > edit > add this one: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin > ok button.

Also I would send my System variables you may need

[image: System variables]

I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple,

Open Start Menu -> View Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> System Variables

> Click "**New**"
>  *Variable Name : MAVEN_HOME*
> *Variable Value: C:\apache-maven-3.6.0*
>  Click "**Ok**"

Next Add PATH in Same *System Variables*.

> Click "**New**"
>  *Variable Name : Path*
>  Add a new value by clicking 'New' button in top right corner.
> *Variable Value : %MAVEN_HOME%\bin*
>  Click "**Ok**"

Then Open CMD, then run

> **mvn -version**

That's all folks.

Answer (score 0):

The changes in "System variables" requires system restart to take effect. ( The same for Linux systems also)

Comment: Not in modern Windows 10. Just close your old `cmd.exe` and open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

After doing changes, you need to reopen CMD window. In my case, my terminal window was opened before updating environment variables, and changes were not reflecting there i.e. mvn -version was returning "...not recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

1) Make sure JDK is installed, and “JAVA_HOME” variable is added as Windows environment variable.

1) Download the Maven zip file, for example : apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.zip. Unzip it to the folder you want to install Maven.
Assume you unzip to this folder – C:\Program Files\Apache\maven

3) Set the environment variables using system properties. Add M2_HOME, M2, MAVEN_OPTS to environment variables.

```
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\apache-maven-3.5.0

M2=%M2_HOME%\bin

MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

4) Now append M2 variable to System Path.
Append the string `;%M2%` to the end of the system variable, Path.

5) Open Command Console and run this command `c:\> mvn --version`

you will get bellow output :

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T17:27:37+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3

Java version: 1.7.0_75, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre

Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with java

Comment: Don't use `M2_HOME`, `M2` etc. only put the bin folder of the maven installation in to the path that's it..