# How to run a python script/programs in CMD from another drive or switch drives?

Tags: python, cmd

So I want to run a python script in cmd i wrote the following code:

```
import argparse
import sys

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--x", type=float, default=1.0, help="enter a number: ")
    parser.add_argument("--y", type=float, default=1.0, help="enter a number: ")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sys.stdout.write(str(add(args)))

def add(args):
    return args.x + args.y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And now I want to run it from CMD.
What exactly should I type. specs: Windows 10, python 3.7, python is already added to path. Path of the file is D:\python programs\test.py and i am in C:\Users\username when I start up CMD. My question is: Now I want too run the file from CMD for which I need to probably switch my drive to D:. How do you do that. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try this : python script.py --x 22.2 --y 23.2

Comment: Sorry guys it is python 3.7

Comment: my file path is D:\python programs\test.py so, shall i write is like py \D:\python programs\test.py

Comment: Depending on your installation method, you might have to manually add the Python installation directory to your environmental variables.

Comment: @nostradamus yes! i did add the path manually to the environment variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure your `Python 3.7` is added to **System Environment path** Variable. it is pretty easy like how you add `JRE` or `MAVEN`. Just follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119595/how-to-add-maven-to-the-path-variable) but do it for Python.
2. Open **CMD** in any arbitrary path and type `python --version`. it ***must*** provide you the version of your python. Something like `Python 3.7.4`
3. In the **navbar** of *the folder that your file exist*, write CMD and hit *Enter*. It must open a **cmd** for you and find the **test.py**. To make sure, your cmd is in correct path, please type **`dir`** and hit enter. It must show the name of your file.
4. If it was fine, then you can safely call `python test.py` and it runs your code.

Comment: Python is already added to my **System Environment path**. I get this error when I try to do that "python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". By the way will this work if my script is in another directory?

Comment: well the `ls` command is giving me a error which says:  `'ls'` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file but the command `python test.py` works. Thanks! for your help.

Comment: @uravgcodddingnoob it was my pleasure. but ls must also work, i don't know why it is not recognized in your machine.

Comment: ahh ! got it I think instead of `ls` i should use `dir` because i am on windows and `ls` is a unix command!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Open Command Prompt (Click on start, write command, press enter)
- Navigate to your script's folder (e.g. cd your_script_folder)
- Run your script using the python command (e.g. python your_script_name.py --x 10.1 --y 20.2)

Please note that you need to be sure about your Python executable's location in case you did not fill out the system variables correctly.

This is very easy to uderstand, if you can write python --version and it works then you've set the system variables correctly.

Otherwise you will have to fix this issue or use the full path to Python executable to make it work.

For example I can find python executable in my Windows 10 here:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

So for me the final command would be:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe your_script_name.py --x 10.1 --y 20.2
```

Answer (score 0):

cd to directory containing python script

```
cd C:/Desktop/Folder
```

On command line, type

```
python script_name.py
```