# I'm unable to run a python program using python.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program that is supposed to open a random file from a folder named 'Notes'. For that I'm using the module 'os'. When I open the script in IDLE and run it it works perfectly but when I try to run it with python.exe it doesn't work. A window opens momentarily and then disappears but the file doesn't open. Here is the code:

```
import os
from random import randint
def search_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search):
    """Search for the given string in file and return lines containing that string,
    along with line numbers"""
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            # For each line, check if line contains the string
            line_number += 1
            if string_to_search in line:
                # If yes, then add the line number & line as a tuple in the list
                list_of_results.append((line_number,line.rstrip()))
    # Return list of tuples containing line numbers and lines where string is found
    return list_of_results

matched_lines = search_string_in_file('D:/D.txt', 'Notes')
y = randint(1,len(matched_lines))
os.startfile(matched_lines[y][1])
```

The file D.txt has a list of paths of all files in my D drive. The entire python folder is installed in drive D rather than its usual install location.

Comment: what do you mean you _try to run it with python.exe_? in the cmd?

Comment: @Matiiss I double clicked it and it was supposed to open with python.exe since that is the default program set to open .py files on my computer.

Comment: either it finished quickly or there was an exception, I would suggest that you run it from cmd, because python.exe terminates after executing a file so that window won't stay open afterwards while cmd would stay open

Comment: I'm not so sure about there being an exception since it worked perfectly well when run from IDLE. Also, since the installation of Python is in D drive, I am unable to run it in cmd. I also tried to add it to Environment Variables guided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119595/how-to-add-maven-to-the-path-variable) but I probably messed up somewhere since that isn't working either.

Comment: I tried running it using a batch script '@echo off
"D:\Python\python.exe" "D:\random.py"
pause' but it gives me an AttributeError "partially initialized module 'random' has no attribute 'randint' (most likely due to a circular import)"

Comment: don't call your file the name of a module you are also importing in that file

Comment: You're getting that error because you named your script `random.py` and `random` is the name of a built-in Python module.

Comment: @martineau thank you!! It now works like a charm! Though I have to run it with a batch file, it is completely fine with me.

Comment: It's a good idea to add the location of your python executable, which in your case appears to be "D:\Python", to the `PATH` environment variable. I'm sure you can do that correctly.

Comment: You can name your batch file pretty much anything (valid) you want (including `random.bat`). I suggest you do bother doing what @printf just suggested.

Comment: @martineau I initially labelled it random.bat, but I might as well keep it by the same name of the .py file now.

Comment: @printf I finally figured out how to do it. I was only adding a new entry in the system variables but then I realized I had to add the path of the folder to the PATH environment variable as well. That was what I did wrong initially. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, it's running and immediately closing. Try adding `time.sleep(99)` at the end of your program, and see what happens then.

If adding time.sleep does not work, open the terminal and cd into the directory. Run `python3 yourfile.py`. If there is an error, it should appear here.