# How to make an Application on JavaFX with jpackage?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, jpackage

I have read like every jpackage question on overflow, but nothing helps me. When I have a .jar of the FX project, I can't even run the .jar file even though I have the JRE.

My input on IntelliJ Terminal:

**"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin\jpackage.exe" -t exe --name DemoFxApp --app-version 1.0 --input out/artifacts/DemoFxApp_jar/DemoFxApp.jar --dest "C:\Users\user\Desktop" --main-jar DemoFxApp.jar --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-18.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.graphics**

The output is a unexpected Token **-t** and **exe**

I installed this package:

**OpenJDK: 18.0.2.1 | JavaFX-SDK: 18.0.2 | JRE: 1.8.0_341**

My project structur:

```
DemoFxApp
|-out
|  |- artifacts
|     |- DemoFxApp_jar
|        |- DemoFxApp.jar
|
|-src
|  |-main
|    |-java
|    | |-app
|    | | |- SceneSwitch.java
|    | |
|    | |-controller
|    | | |-ControllerFirstScreen.java
|    | | |-ControllerSecondScreen.java
|    | |
|    | |-Launcher.java
|    |
|    |-resources
|      |-FirstScreen.fxml
|      |-SecondScreen.fxml
|
|-pom.xml
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>DemoFxApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoFxApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>18</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <javaFxVersion>18.0.2</javaFxVersion>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javaFxVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javaFxVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javaFxVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javaFxVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I don't know the reason for this, [`-t exe` is a valid option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) that appears to be in the right location in the command line.  I just have a mac, so I can't verify your command on windows.  It probably doesn't make much difference, but does the same error occur when using the windows command prompt rather than IntelliJ terminal?  If you just run jpackage with the `--version` option, does it work?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX) and try using their scripts for packaging your JavaFX app using jpackage.

Comment: The jpackage-maven-plugin should not be a dependency in your app in the current section, instead, it should be in the [build section](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) (or not there if not used at all).  I haven't used the `panteleyev` plugin, but I have used the [akman](https://github.com/Akman/jpackage-maven-plugin) plugin with JavaFX, and that works fine as an alternative to using the command line for packaging.

Comment: For building the jar file, use maven not the Idea artifact mechanism.  Run`mvn package` on your project, you can do that by double-clicking LifeCycle | Package in the maven window in Idea.  The output jar will be located in the `target` directory, not the `out` directory, and it is the jar from the target which should be used as input to jpackage.

Comment: 1) jpackage --version doesn't work. I did the envoirenment variable to jpackage: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin\jpackage.exe" | 2) JPackageScriptFX I can not follow the step because I don't understand it. | 3) I wrote the mvn package on the Terminal and get an error that said that they not know what mvn is. | I have just edited my pom.xml

Comment: "on the Terminal and get an error that said that they not know what mvn is" -> Here is a guide for [Windows setup for maven environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119595/how-to-add-maven-to-the-path-variable) which allows you to use maven on your path from the command line without needing to specify the full path to the mvn executable each time you run it.  Setting the path to maven isn't necessary for invoking maven from your IDE as the IDE will be preconfigured to access and use a version of maven it ships with.

Comment: "`jpackage --version` doesn't work." -> it should work.  On my setup it outputs `17.0.2`, which is the version being used.  Likely your environment settings (path variable) is wrong.  I don't know the specifics of what you have wrong, but you could do some research on how to set environment path variables on windows.

Comment: You don't need the `maven-jar-plugin` section in your pom.xml. Maven knows how to package jar files by default and I think the custom configuration with a `test` classifier is wrong.

Comment: I can see on the terminal the versions of java, jpackage and maven. But when I use this input on the intellij terminal `jpackage --type exe --input out/artifacts/DemoFxApp_jar --dest "C:\Users\user\Documents" --main-jar .\DemoFxApp.jar --main-class main.java.Launcher --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-18.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.graphics`. I get an **installer** and when I run it nothing happens. No **exe** file to see but I want make an **exe** and not an **installer**.

Comment: There is a guide to making an exe without an installer in the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).   To add additional info, you can edit the question, it can be more readable than comments to do that sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but somehow I feel like it's not working for me. I give up with jpackage.